# javascript code to get the html tag information and store in a variable in js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page with content and a button. When clicked on the `getData` button, a javascript function is called where I have to store each html tag information to a variable.

Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/wuIsu1qhcrYeoxtkrGxC?p=preview

js code:

```
function getData(){
        var $divs = $('.div1')      
        alert($divs);   //[object Object] is printed
      //var p_tags;
      //var ul_tags;
    }
```

html code:

```
 <div>
        <button onClick="getData()">GetData</button>

   <div class="div1">
<p>The identity of the longest word in English depends upon the definition of what constitutes a word in the English language, as well as how length should be compared. In addition to words derived naturally from the language's roots (without any known intentional invention), English allows new words to be formed by coinage and construction; place names may be considered words; technical terms may be arbitrarily long. Length may be understood in terms of orthography and number of written letters, or (less commonly) </p>

<p><span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic;">This article is about the Internet encyclopedia. For Wikipedia's home page, see&nbsp;</span><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" title="Main Page" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic;">Wikipedia's Main Page</a><span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic;">. For Wikipedia's visitor introduction, see&nbsp;</span><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:About" title="Wikipedia:About" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic;">Wikipedia's About Page</a><span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic;">. For other uses, see&nbsp;</span><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_(disambiguation)" class="mw-disambig" title="Wikipedia (disambiguation)" style="text-decoration-line: underline; color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic;">Wikipedia&nbsp;</a></p>
<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>
  </div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

What you try to output via `alert` is a jQuery object. Browser `alert` cannot show the details of objects — instead `[object Object]` is printed.

However, if you try `console.log($divs)`, you can see the details of the jQuery object, on which you can execute various methods to manipulate DOM.

[image]

For example, you can get the inner HTML of the selected `<div>`s like this:

```
console.log($divs.html())
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it prints [object Object] but it has a little expando-toggly button.So,loop through the elements in it and display it.

```
console.log($divs.html())
```

Answer (score -2):

Use text() method to get tag information

```
function getData(){
    var $divs = $('.div1').text();   

    var p_tags = $('.div1 p').text();
    var ul_tags = $('.div1 ul').text();
}
```

In Case you want full HTMl then use html() method.